# Ranking with time weighting

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, math

I am looking for a basic algorithm that gives more weigh to the recent reviews.

So, the output value of the algorithm is mutable. For example, two reviews with exactly the same score, will have a different ranking based on the timestamp of the creation.

```
Review_1
Score 10
creation 10/5/2014

Review_2 
Score 10
creation 10/5/2015
```

A ponderation like:

```
1 if review ts < 1 year
0.5 if review > year
```

So, I can use something like `(review_1.score * 1) + (review_1.score * 0.5)`.

However, if both reviews are old doesn't make sense `(review_1.score * 0.5) + (review_1.score * 0.5)`, right? The overall will be half of the original score only because there are no new reviews.

Comment: Consider the timestamp of the most recent review as 'present' for the pupose of weighting.

Comment: You're only weighting the numerator; weight the denominator, too. Or aren't you doing an average?

Comment: @DanGetz, i don't see how that solves the issue. But yes, i am doing an average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify @Dan Getz and add @collapsar answer I will add the following:

Dan's Formula is correct:

`(score1 * weight1 + ... + scoreN * weightN) / (weight1 + ... + weightN)`

The beauty of the weighted average is **you get to choose** the weights!

So we choose days since the first message as the weight.  So I will choose some data and show how this works.  In all cases the simple average is 5.0 .

First we will look at ratings that have increased over time.

```
Date[0]:  May 6      Rating[0]: 1     Weight[0]: 0
Date[1]:  May 7      Rating[1]: 3     Weight[1]: 1
Date[2]:  May 8      Rating[2]: 5     Weight[2]: 2
Date[3]:  May 9      Rating[3]: 7     Weight[3]: 3
Date[4]:  May 10     Rating[4]: 9     Weight[4]: 4
```

so to calculate the weights:

```
Weight[i] = Date[i] - Date[0]
```

To calculate the average

```
( Rating[0]*Weight[0] + Rating[1]*Weight[1] + ... + Rating[N]*Weight[N] ) / 
( Weight[0] + Weight[1] + ... + Weight[N] )
```

The Calculation:

```
(1*0 + 3*1 + 5*2 + 7*3 + 9*4) / (0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = (0+3+10+21+36)/10 = 7.0
```

Similarly a rating that has decreased over time:

```
Date[0]:  May 6      Rating[0]: 9     Weight[0]: 0
Date[1]:  May 7      Rating[1]: 7     Weight[1]: 1
Date[2]:  May 8      Rating[2]: 5     Weight[2]: 2
Date[3]:  May 9      Rating[3]: 3     Weight[3]: 3
Date[4]:  May 10     Rating[4]: 1     Weight[4]: 4
```

The Calculation will be:

```
(9*0 + 7*1 + 5*2 + 3*3 + 1*4) / (0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = (0+7+10+9+4)/10 = 3.0
```

I **chose** the weight such that the larger weights correspond to the ratings I wanted to have more weight.

Answer (score 0):

To do a weighted average, instead of dividing the weighted total by the number of scores, divide the weighted total by the total weight.

## Explanation

When you do a normal average of `N` scores which can range from 0 to `maxScore`, you start by adding all the scores:

```
score1 + score2 + ... + scoreN
```

This value can range, depending on the individual scores, from 0 to `maxScore * N`. So to transform it to range from 0 to `maxScore`, we should divide by `N`:

```
(score1 + score2 + ... + scoreN) / N
```

If you do a weighted average, the total of the scores has a different formula:

```
score1 * weight1 + score2 * weight2 + ... + scoreN * weightN
```

This no longer is going to range from 0 to `N * maxScore`, so it doesn't make sense to divide by `N` anymore. It ranges from 0 to:

```
maxScore * weight1 + maxScore * weight2 + ... + maxScore * weightN
```

which is `maxScore * totalWeight`. So to transform your weighted total into a weighted average, we need to divide by the total weight:

```
(score1 * weight1 + ... + scoreN * weightN) / (weight1 + ... + weightN)
```

Note that if you set each weight equal to 1, you get the formula for a normal average, which is a sign that we might have done this math right.

Comment: Dan, my question is how this solves the issue of the time weighting?

Comment: Well, I thought I answered the question that you asked—how to make the average make sense when you do a time weighting like the one you described in your question. You already had figured out what weight to give each score, so if you felt it was going to give an artificially low result, that was because you weren't doing the weighted average right.

Comment: I think the comment of @collapsar is the only answer here that focus on the issue. thanks anyway.

Comment: So it turns out you're not at all worried that "The overall will be half of the original score only because there are no new reviews."?